# href attribute of <a> not being set

Tags: jquery

In my application, I send an AJAX request to a server, and based on some data, I have to change the **href** attribute of  element. Here's my code:

```
$('#unclaimed_codes_list li').map(function(){
    $(this).children("a:first").text(fname + ' ' + lname + '(' + key + ')');
}

$.get('/accs/get_val/' + key, function(data){
    var edit_href = '/ak_access_levels/' + id + '/edit';
    alert(edit_href);
    $(this).children("a:first").attr('href', 'edit_href');
});
```

But its not working. I can see that my edit_href value is correct, but still, the href attribute is not being set. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: I can't believe that `$(this)` (at `$.get`) is pointing to a HTML element. Check your code.

Comment: Also, you're assigning a string with content `'edit_href'` to the href attribute, not the `edit_href` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the second occurence of `$(this).children('a:first')` by `$('#unclaimed_codes_list li a:first')`. Secondly, change `'edit_href'` to `edit_href`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I had edit_href, not 'edit_href' anyways, $('#unclaimed_codes_list li a:first') did the trick. Thanks.